# iPython notebook error when trying to load matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, anaconda

I'm trying to learn pandas by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JnMutdy6Fw. I downloaded the notebooks (https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial/), and loaded up Exercises-1. The first block

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
```

is giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5761ac74df30> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
      2 import pandas as pd

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2305         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2306         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2307         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2308 
   2309     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2226                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2227             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2228                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2229             return result
   2230 

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)
     86         """
     87         args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(self.matplotlib, line)
---> 88         gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
     89         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
     90 

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3087         """
   3088         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3089         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3090 
   3091         if gui != 'inline':

/Users/***/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    237     """
    238 
--> 239     import matplotlib
    240 
    241     if gui and gui != 'auto':

/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    178 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    179 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 180 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
    181 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    182 

/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py in <module>()
     31 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     32 
---> 33 import numpy as np
     34 import numpy.ma as ma
     35 

/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    183         return loader(*packages, **options)
    184 
--> 185     from . import add_newdocs
    186     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    187                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/Users/***/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from .ufunclike import *
     16 
---> 17 from . import scimath as emath
     18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode

ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

Can someone tell me what's happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238004/ipython-notebook-throws-importerror-ipython-doesnt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622021/1766755).

The main problem is with importing scimath:
"ImportError: cannot import name scimath"

You can try to import scimath.

A better solution would be to set your PYTHONPATH var, which provides the python interpreter with additional directories look in for python packages/modules. You can read more about setting PYTHONPATH variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just updated my canopy modules and set my PYTHONPATH to include anaconda and it worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear! :)