# Calling a Python function from another file in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm in the ipython shell and can't import a function from other file.
When I try:

```
from my_functions import this_function
```

I got:

> No module named my_functions

But if I try the save from other file it works.

Yes, I opened the shell in the same directory of `my_functions` file.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script

Comment: Check your working directory using `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Try `from .my_functions import this_function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder')
```

solved the problem.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35493019/2) to the question [Calling a Python function from another file in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493019/calling-a-python-function-from-another-file-in-ipython) by the OP [Luis Ramon Ramirez Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4544413/luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Comment: The better solution is to install your code in a way that doesn't require modifying `sys.path` at runtime. Use a virtual environment, and package your code so that it can be installed in a virtual environment using `pip` or some other tool.