# Why the import of google.protobuf works fine in ipython but not in python?

Tags: python, import, ipython, importerror, protocol-buffers

In ipython

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import google.protobuf

In [2]:
```

However in python:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
>>> import google.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named protobuf
>>>
```

Why this strange error happened? Please help me figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is due to some conflicts between my anaconda package of protobuf and the system's protobuf. After uninstalling protobuf

`pip uninstall protobuf
conda uninstall protobuf`

and reinstalling

`conda install protobuf`

everything goes fine now.