# Error while working with Cython

Tags: python, cython, python-3.5

I'm facing a problem with Cython. I created the following two files in the same directory.

< sample.pyx >

```
print("hello world!")
```

< test.py >

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import sample
```

When I run test.py, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-15-e135bfea2262>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/itsez/Desktop/python/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/itsez/Desktop/python')

File "C:\Users\itsez\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\itsez\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/itsez/Desktop/python/test.py", line 3, in <module>
import sample

File "C:\Users\itsez\Desktop\python\pyximport.py", line 435, in load_module

File "C:\Users\itsez\Desktop\python\pyximport.py", line 225, in load_module

File "C:\Users\itsez\Desktop\python\pyximport.py", line 209, in load_module

File "C:\Users\itsez\Desktop\python\pyximport.py", line 180, in build_module

ImportError: Building module sample failed: ["SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import\n"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux

Comment: I'm using Windows10, maybe that's the reason pyximport doesn't work.

Comment: it shouldn't be - cython is cross-platform. Have you used it successfully before? How did you install it? What version do you have?

Comment: This is the first time I use Cython. I installed the latest version of Anaconda for windows 32-bit yesterday. After the installation, I updated Cython by using "conda update cython".

Comment: Are you using ipython? Maybe your problem is related to something like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15622021/5781248