# Provide temporary PYTHONPATH on the commandline?

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonpath

I'm thinking of something like

`python3 my_script.py --pythonpath /path/to/some/necessary/modules`

Is there something like this? I know (I think) that Pycharm temporarily modifies `PYTHONPATH` when you use it to execute scripts; how does Pycharm do it?

### Reasons I want to do this (you don't really need to read the following)

The reason I want to do this is that I have some code that usually needs to run on my own machine (which is fine because I use Pycharm to run it) but sometimes needs to run on a remote server (on the commandline), and it doesn't work because the remote server doesn't have the `PYTHONPATH`s that Pycharm automatically temporarily adds. I don't want to `export PYTHONPATH=[...]` because it's a big hassle to change it often (and suppose it really does need to change often).

Comment: you could also `import sys` and `append` the necessary path to `sys.path` at the head of your program

Comment: @Andrew I didn't want to use the `sys.path.append()` trick because I want to keep my code clean and platform-independent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the python path in an environment variable like so:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/some/necessary/modules python3 my_script.py
```

Comment: Just the solution I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much effort you want to put into this temporary python path thing but you could always use a python virtual environment for running scripts or whatever you need.