# Jupyter Notebook: Import .ipynb file and access it's method in other .ipynb file giving error

Tags: python, module, anaconda, jupyter, user-defined

I am fairly new to Jupyter Notebook. I have played around with it for a while. But this was my first time trying to import another notebook into my main class.

For reference, I am using Anaconda 4.3.1 and Python v2.7.

I am trying to replicate what I did in my python project to jupyter notebooks. It requires importing other .ipynb files (translated from the original .py files) into it to use relevant methods as desired.

For this, I followed the directions as given on Jupyter Nbviewer [Steps Link](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb) which I found through my preliminary search on the following stack [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file). It gave me some idea but didn't help me after one stage.

I will walk you through the steps I took and the sample program I tried.

1. Created a small .ipynb file abc.ipynb as follows

   ```
   def prt_n(str):
       print(str)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       prt_n("in abc")
   ```
2. Created an .ipynb file to import Jupyter Notebook from the Jupyter link given above. Say, importer.ipynb.
3. Run importer.ipynb
4. `import abc`
5. `str="Hello Me"`
6. Test step `abc.__name__` results in `abc` as output.
7. `abc.prt_n(str)` throws following error

*---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2fb88a43c9e5> in <module>()
```

----> 1 abc.prt_n(str)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'prt_n'*

I was hoping that the answer will be `Hello Me`.

Later, I want to actually create a myMain.ipynb file and in that I want to include 2-3 such notebooks and call their methods with required parameters.

One such example can be a file `efg.ipynb` as follows:

`import abc
a="Hello Notebook"
abc.prt_n(a)`

I also want to make sure if there is any other way to do this?

Note: I have already checked sys.executable and sys.path. Both have the same python path value.

Any sort of help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**

> Link to sample files on [Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-RbGo767y2NaGdtc2U3cEVMWW8)

**

Ok. So, after some struggle and looking around on Internet, and finally found a solution that worked for my sample case.

Firstly, this is the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script) question that was the most helpful to me. Mohideen and Tyhela's answer was the actual solution and not the one with most number of votes.

So, what I did was, I made a folder by the name module and placed all my .ipynb files there. Plus, I created an `__init__.py` file in that module  by using `touch __init__.py` command such that the import can register it as a valid module. Those guys have given a detailed explanation for it which seems legit.

Then from my working directory I ran the following commands:

```
str = "Hello Me"
import test.abc as tabc
tabc.prt_n(str)
```

that gave me `Hello Me` in the output.

And for,

```
`import test.efg as tefg`
```

I got

`importing Jupyter notebook from test/efg.ipynb
Hello Note`

As my desired output.

I hope this will be of help to others who land up on similar problem.

If you have a better approach then I will appreciate if you can share that with me.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Simple way to use ipynb files in jupyter note book are as follows:

1) Install `import-ipynb`

```
pip install import-ipynb
```

2) Import `import_ipynb` in jupyter notebook. Then import ipynb file as you import .py file

```
import import_ipynb
from test import print_name

print_name("your name")
```