# How to import a .ipynb file into another

Tags: python, import, anaconda

I am using `anaconda2` and the version of `python` I am running is `3.7.0`

How do I import one `.ipynb` file into another?

I have installed a package called `import_ipynb` using `pip` and when importing the package into my notebook I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import_ipynb'
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336087/jupyter-notebook-import-ipynb-file-and-access-its-method-in-other-ipynb-file

Comment: are you having more than python version installed?

Comment: I have installed python 3.7.0. I just ran python -V command to check the current version and I got the same result, 3.7.0

Comment: install `import_ipynb` using `pip3`

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `pip freeze` and pip3 `freeze`?

Comment: I solved the issue. There was a conflict in importing the import_ipynb package. So, I imported the import_ipynb.py file and it works fine. Thanks for the support!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186344/ipynb-import-another-ipynb-file