# Setting pythonpath on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to add a permanent `PYTHONPATH` using `Jupyter Notebook` to be able to access the data from a particular directory or folder. I have read that we could use `JUPYTER_PATH` for it.

Could someone tell me a step wise instruction on how to do it. I am new to it and the documentation was not very clear.

For example sake lets say my path is as follows:
`C:\ENG\Fin_trade\ION`

Comment: I have same issue and summary on  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158616/2224000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a script that needs to reference your directory, you can do the following.

Say you have the file foo.py containing the class Foo in your directory C:\ENG\Fin_trade\ION

```
import os
import sys

new_path = r'C:\ENG\Fin_trade\ION'
sys.path.append(new_path)

import foo

Foo()
```

Comment: Here you seem to be giving a piece of code to run inside each notebook.   Sinto asks how "to add a permanent PYTHONPATH", meaning, as I read it, put it in the path before any code *inside* a Jupyter notebook is run.  Is there a configuration file where we should put your code snippet to have this effect?

Comment: Each operating system has its own method of udating environment variables. You need to search for a solution for the particular OS that you use.

Comment: This answer does not always work. If inside the package `foo` there is a call to a method that's in `ION` then that method will not be found.

As for setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH, this requires launching Jupyter again.