# Failed use command "import os" in Linux command?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm following the Machine learning tutorial made by [Google Developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#3). When  executing the command:

```
python -m scripts.retrain -h
```

I get the result:

```
> /usr/bin/python: No module named scripts
```

I tried to search for a result, and I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script) from stackoverflow:

> If you run

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

> you'll see this is true.
>   But what I get is this:

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `os' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you running those command in an interactive python interpreter?  It looks like you're trying to run them directly in your shell.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558605/import-im6-q16-not-authorized-error-os-error-constitue-c-writeimage-1037-fo

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you have to update the policy for ImageMagick library.

Please check the settings in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`.
There lots of policy rules and you can experiment with them to find the correct solution. For me, to solve `import-im6.q16: not authorized` error worked next settings:

```
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PS" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="EPI" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="XPS" />
```

Initially these lines had `rights` attribute equal to `none` like this:

```
 <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
```