# how could I install matplotlib correctly on ubuntu?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib

> pip install matplotlib

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools-lru-cache in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: subprocess32 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (44.1.1)
```

when I try to verify the version installed

> import matplotlib
>
> matplotlib.**version**

I get this:

`import-im6.q16: not authorized` matplotlib' @error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.`

What is the problem? Thank you

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem. Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: When you run the installer it installs all the packages in the package list

Comment: Why is anaconda being recommended? It is HUGE, comes with side-effects, and could cause more problems than it solves...

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Looking into your error message in more detail, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558605/import-im6-q16-not-authorized-error-os-error-constitue-c-writeimage-1037-fo).

It seems like your interpreter is not recognizing your script as python and is instead trying to use this [tool](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/imagemagick-6.q16/import-im6.q16.1.en.html).

Possibly try adding a shebang to your python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or run it explicitly with python:

```
# if /usr/bin/env python is python3
python myscript.py
# if not
python3 myscript.py
```

### Original answer

It looks like you are trying to install with a Python2.7 pip. Python 2 is no longer really supported by anyone, so I recommend using Python 3 instead.

To install with python3, maybe try:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

If you want to update your default pip, you might try the following (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-upgrade-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The comment to instead use [conda](http://%20Miniconda%20%E2%80%94%20Conda%20documentationhttps://conda.io%20%E2%80%BA%20miniconda) is a good call also. Then you can simply do something like

```
conda create -n plots -c conda-forge python=3.9 matplotlib
conda activate plots
```

And matplotlib will be part of that python3 env.

Comment: Hi @Maximilian Press, I tried `pip3 install matplotlib` but if I try to very the versio of matplotlib installed with `import matplotlib
                                     matplotlib.__version__`
 I get  ` import-im6.q16: not authorized `matplotlib' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.`

Comment: the default python is 3.9 for conda and matplotlib is installed by default so there's not a need to install a separate environment.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I should download one of these?                                                   64-Bit (x86) Installer (581 MB)
64-Bit (Power8 and Power9) Installer (255 MB)
64-Bit (AWS Graviton2 / ARM64) Installer (488 M)
64-bit (Linux on IBM Z & LinuxONE) Installer (242 M)                                                             and then run `conda install package`?

Comment: @Vale try the installer for the operating system you are using

Comment: well, I don't know what I've done... rigth now my situsation is this;                                 pip -V
pip 21.3.1 from /home/valeria/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)                 python --version
Python 3.6.9
 python -m pip install -U matplotlib
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Comment: @Vale see my update from Friday. It looks like you are not running using the python interpreter. Instead follow suggested methods to run using the python interpreter.

Comment: Hi @MaximilianPress I tried but then I don't know what I did and I deleted packages on ubuntu, so I have to install ubuntu again.  I did a mess. At the moment I haven't fixed it. Thank you anyway