# only part of modules in same directory can be imported in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I created a new project (myproject) and 3 python files in a row (mainscript.py, module1.py, module2.py) in the directory.
In main script, I coded:

```
import module1
import module2
```

The two empty modules were imported without problem. After this, I created a 3rd python file (module3.py) in the same directory.
When I tried to run:

```
import module3
```

I got the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-b4e6aa7db43e>", line 1, in <module>
    import module3
  File "E:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module3'
```

Can someone explain why the first two files are detected and not the third?

After trying several times the experiment, it seems that only the files created before I run for the first time import function will be found.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you getting that error when you use python console?

Comment: I am also getting an error from the python console, but that is because the python programme is in another file and I do not know how to specify the directory. Regarding the import on Charm, I realised that when I close and open the program again the other created modules can be imported. However this means I have to close and open Pycharm very time I create or change one of my modules.

Comment: Try the following in terminal and show what output you are getting: `python --version`

Comment: I obtain this whith `python --version` : `Python 3.7.6`

Comment: Create an empty python file with the name `__init__.py` in the directory.

Comment: I added one in my directorybut it is still not working

Comment: `import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder')` and use your complete directory path.

Comment: sadly that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Check this link and see if solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script