# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, chatbot, chatterbot

I am not able to understand how to create the link for the package as I have installed the package but it does not work. I am not able to understand why it is not working.

Kindly, help me out with this project. I need to make a "Sales Automation Chatbot". But if libraries are not working then it is a problem for me.

from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import spacy

```
Bot = ChatBot(name='PyBot', read_only=True,
             logic_adapters=['chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
                             'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'])


Error: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-298f9ccedff4> in <module>
      1 Bot = ChatBot(name='PyBot', read_only=True,
      2                  logic_adapters=['chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
----> 3                                  'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'])

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py in __init__(self, name, **kwargs)
     26         self.logic_adapters = []
     27 
---> 28         self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
     29 
     30         primary_search_algorithm = IndexedTextSearch(self, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py in initialize_class(data, *args, **kwargs)
     31         Class = import_module(data)
     32 
---> 33         return Class(*args, **kwargs)
     34 
     35 

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     18 
     19     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
---> 20         super().__init__(**kwargs)
     21 
     22         from sqlalchemy import create_engine

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     19 
     20         self.tagger = PosLemmaTagger(language=kwargs.get(
---> 21             'tagger_language', languages.ENG
     22         ))
     23 

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py in __init__(self, language)
     11         self.punctuation_table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation))
     12 
---> 13         self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
     14 
     15     def get_bigram_pair_string(self, text):

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     28     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     29         warnings.warn(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path), DeprecationWarning)
---> 30     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     31 
     32 

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    168             return load_model_from_link(name, **overrides)
    169         if is_package(name):  # installed as package
--> 170             return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
    171         if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
    172             return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **overrides)

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
    188 def load_model_from_package(name, **overrides):
    189     """Load a model from an installed package."""
--> 190     cls = importlib.import_module(name)
    191     return cls.load(**overrides)
    192 

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\Anaconda\envs\chatbot\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script. Check they are on the same interpreter: $ ipython3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'; $ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Comment: I don't see where you've imported chatbot...

Comment: I have imported my chatbot in anaconda prompt