# ModuleNotFoundError with python transformers library despite it being installed in venv when running invoke task

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, python-venv, pyinvoke

Title. I'm currently trying to run import a module that uses transformers but it throws the following error:

```
(tf2venv) dante@dante-Inspiron-5570:~/projects/classification$ inv process-pdf test.pdf
Using TensorFlow backend.
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/bin/inv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(program.run())
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 373, in run
    self.parse_collection()
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 465, in parse_collection
    self.load_collection()
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 696, in load_collection
    module, parent = loader.load(coll_name)
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/invoke/loader.py", line 76, in load
    module = imp.load_module(name, fd, path, desc)
  File "/home/dante/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/dante/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/tasks.py", line 10, in <module>
    from app import ClassifyDocument
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from docType_classification import classify, grouping, utils
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/docType_classification/classify.py", line 13, in <module>
    import common.hybrid as hybrid
  File "/home/dante/projects/classification/common/hybrid.py", line 3, in <module>
    import transformers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'
```

The code in `common/hybrid.py` is as follows:

```
import transformers
from tokenizers import BertWordPieceTokenizer
import tqdm
import numpy as np

def build_tokenizer():
    # load the real tokenizer
    tokenizer = transformers.DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        "distilbert-base-uncased"
    )
    # Save the loaded tokenizer locally
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(".")
    # Reload it with the huggingface tokenizers library
    hugging_face_tokenizer = BertWordPieceTokenizer("vocab.txt", lowercase=False)
    return hugging_face_tokenizer


def encode(texts, tokenizer, chunk_size=256, maxlen=512):
    tokenizer.enable_truncation(max_length=maxlen)
    tokenizer.enable_padding(length=maxlen)
    all_ids = []

    print(len(texts))
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(texts), chunk_size)):
        text_chunk = texts[i : i + chunk_size].tolist()
        encs = tokenizer.encode_batch(text_chunk)
        all_ids.extend([enc.ids for enc in encs])

    return np.array(all_ids)
```

It is imported in `classify.py` as:

```
import common.hybrid as hybrid
```

I'm able to compile and run this file with

```
python3 common/hybrid.py
```

without any errors.

When running an invoke task with

```
invoke process-data
```

the file tasks.py is located in the root project directory.

I get the `ModuleNotFoundError` as soon as it reaches the transformers import.

Note that even when adding

```
import tensorflow
```

above the transformers import, this is imported correctly and the error isn't thrown until

```
import transformers
```

`pip freeze` output:

```
absl-py==0.12.0
appdirs==1.4.4
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==20.3.0
backcall==0.2.0
bearbones==2.300
black==20.8b1
boto3==1.9.85
botocore==1.12.253
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2020.12.5
cfgv==3.2.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
decorator==5.0.6
distlib==0.3.1
docutils==0.15.2
fancycompleter==0.9.1
filelock==3.0.12
flake8==3.9.0
fuzzysearch==0.7.3
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.28.1
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.37.0
h5py==2.10.0
identify==2.2.3
idna==2.8
invoke==1.5.0
ipython==7.14.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==5.8.0
jedi==0.18.0
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==1.0.1
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
lxml==4.6.3
Markdown==3.3.4
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==8.7.0
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
nodeenv==1.6.0
numpy==1.20.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==20.9
pandas==1.1.5
parso==0.8.2
pathspec==0.8.1
pdbpp==0.10.2
pdf2image==1.10.0
pdftotext==2.1.5
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pikepdf==1.7.1
Pillow==8.2.0
pipdeptree==2.0.0
pluggy==0.13.1
pre-commit==2.12.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
protobuf==3.15.8
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py==1.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pyflakes==2.3.1
Pygments==2.8.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pyrepl==0.9.0
pytest==5.3.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
redis==3.3.11
regex==2021.4.4
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
sacremoses==0.0.44
scipy==1.4.1
sentencepiece==0.1.95
six==1.15.0
tenacity==6.0.0
tensorboard==2.2.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.2.0
termcolor==1.1.0
tokenizers==0.10.2
toml==0.10.2
tqdm==4.60.0
traitlets==5.0.5
transformers==4.4.2
typed-ast==1.4.3
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==20.4.3
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wmctrl==0.3
wrapt==1.12.1
```

other info:

```
(tf2venv) dante@dante-Inspiron-5570:~/projects/classification$ which python
/home/dante/projects/classification/tf2venv/bin/python
(tf2venv) dante@dante-Inspiron-5570:~/projects/classification$ which inv
/home/dante/projects/classification/tf2venv/bin/inv
(tf2venv) dante@dante-Inspiron-5570:~/projects/classification$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
```

Note that there are no circular imports and I've tried various versions of transformers(v3-4)

Everything was installed with `pip3`, the `venv` was created with

```
python3 -m venv tf2venv
```

I've tried deleting the `venv` and reinstalling various times but nothing works. Is there something missing that is causing this ModuleNotFoundError with transformers?

My `requirements.txt` is

```
bearbones>=2
fuzzysearch~=0.7.3
ipython~=7.14.0
Keras~=2.3.0
pdf2image~=1.10.0
pikepdf~=1.7.0
tenacity~=6.0.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
transformers==3.0.2
pandas~=1.1.5
pytest~=5.3.2
pdftotext~=2.1.4
```

Comment: Activate your environment and then do "pip list --local". Do you see the transformers in the output? pip list --local only shows the installed packages in the local environment.

Comment: Make sure your code is running in environment where Transformers is installed. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue, this worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script/15622021#15622021