# Importing numpy and scipy libraries in python in virtual environment

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I created virtual environment in my `D:` Drive in the folder `vir` in python.
In command prompt I have been trying

> `pip install numpy` and `pip install scipy`

It gets installed there but when I run the command

> `import numpy`

> `import scipy`

in my `jupyter` notebook, it shows the error :

> `ModuleNotFoundError`

I have tried installing and uninstalling several times but nothing is happening. I installed both the libraries in `vir` folder only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses for this issue.
First, try to install again with specific version

```
python -m pip install '$PACKAGE_NAME==$VERSION_NUMBER'
```

Then if it still does not work, maybe the packages are installed but not activated. Try to activate the packet

```
conda activate packet_name
```

Comment: what is '$package name==$version number' for numpy and scipy. I am a beginner, please tell

Comment: the package name would be numpy and scipy. For the version number you can use basiclly any version you want. The newest versions are numpy: 1.21.0 and scipy: 1.7.0

Comment: Nice! Please select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you must activate the new environment you just create it , to do so
if you are using anaconda
[image: anaconda you can see all the environment]

new environment must be under base (root) so you click on the new env and then open terminal
[image: details]
after that you put this line to make sure it activated

```
conda activate yourenv
```

and then install your lib like this

```
pip install numpy 
pip install scipy
```

and make sure when you open your Jupiter choose your env like this

[image]

Comment: this link could help https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: I did not install jupyter notebook through anaconda

Comment: then you can activate your new env like this 
if git installed and your device is windows
source env/scripts/activate
if mac
source env/bin/activate

Comment: I already activated my virtualenv and it is working also but I am not able to import libraries there. I am getting the error module not found

Comment: could you please do this 
**pip freeze** 
you can see all library in your env 
if you found them ,i can tell you that you are not open the Jupiter in the same env

Comment: Hi! @Ahmad Omar, the problem is solved. Now, I am able to import the libraries.. Thank you.