# "No module named cobra.test"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

I have the code

[image]

And get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cobra.test'"
Seems to be a common problem on Google but I can't find any solutions. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)