# Jupyter Notebook : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, pip, sqlalchemy, module, jupyter-notebook

I have installed sqlalchemy and its getting imported in python in powershell

[image]

But when I am trying to import in jupyter notebook, its showing module not found error.

I tried installing it in the notebook and then importing it but no success

[image]

I am really stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a guess but maybe you need to reopen the notebook after installing - python does not reload its installations before you do it.

Answer (score -2):

I got the solution from this post

["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script/15622021#15622021)

I had to add the path of the module folder to sys.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder')
import sqlalchemy
```